# How to make transparent Color background for camera preview exuding one View?

Tags: android, xml, layout, view, preview

I want to make a scanner-like view for my camera preview I have created a view with a rectangle view in the center of the camera preview now I want to add a transparent color background to the camera preview but want to make a rectangle clear view. I have tried with set alpha and background color but it is not working in my view.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/preview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />



<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/switchcamera"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="camera_change"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:src="@drawable/frontcamera_foreground"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/preview"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_animator"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:text="1"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="70sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/viewRectangle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:alpha="1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

here FrameLayout is for the preview of the camera using custom SurfaceView
View is my RectangleView.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

Ignore `com.otaliastudios.cameraview.CameraView` it's just a camera library I have imported.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <com.otaliastudios.cameraview.CameraView
        android:id="@+id/camera"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/viewRectangle"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Now the important part is how `border.xml` drawable is constructed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
    <stroke android:color="#a00" android:width="1dp"/>
</shape>
```

Notice that solid part is set to transparent and only stroke is given a solid color.This was you can achieve it.